# Show waiting symbol while binding large datatable to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am binding a fairly large datatable to a datagrid, and this takes some time.

I am wanting to show the user some sort of waiting symbol, what that is I don't care at the moment. However I am not sure how to get some sort of datatrigger when the binding has completed and the datagrid updated.

Would anyone be able to offer any advice on how to get a datatrigger to show a binding operation has finished?

Comment: If it's the actual binding that's taking a while, your UI thread is blocked, and there's not much you can do at that point.  But you could set up a wait indicator, then schedule a callback to clear it using `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` immediately before binding your grid.  It's hacky, though, and makes things more complicated than simply binding to the data source in XAML.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked great for me as a solution.